# no access to html - trying to style some text bigger

Tags: css, label

I'm using a CMS to try and alter a fundraising form so the text is bigger.

I've managed to alter the paragraph and `<h>` easily enough but there are some stubborn labels that i cant get to go bigger - here is one - I'd like the words "Payment Frequency" to be 20px or so....

```
<div class="field select required">

    <label for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_DropDownList" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_LabelForDropDownList">***Payment Frequency***</label>
    <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder234$FormControl1$DonationSection$DropDownPaymentFrequency$DropDownList" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_DropDownList">
        <option value="">Please Select...</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
        <option value="Annually">Annually</option>

    </select>    
</div>
```

I have been able to style these individually but there must be a better way, there are loads of them, here is another example:

```
<div class="field text date required">

    <label for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_CollectionDate_DropDownListDay" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_CollectionDate_LabelTextBoxCollectionDate">Collection date </label>
```

I tried styling all "labels" but only the first one changed. the rest stayed the same.

Comment: you have tried `.field label {font-size:20px!important;}`?

Comment: `ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_LabelForDropDownList` - what a spectacular ID...

Comment: @thirtydot ASP.NET webforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be another CSS rule which is overwriting your new CSS rule. You can use the `!important` to overwrite an already existing CSS rule. See the following:

```css
div.field label {
  font-size:20px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="field select required">
  <label for="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_DropDownList" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_LabelForDropDownList">***Payment Frequency***</label>
  <select name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder234$FormControl1$DonationSection$DropDownPaymentFrequency$DropDownList" id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder234_FormControl1_DonationSection_DropDownPaymentFrequency_DropDownList">
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
    <option value="Annually">Annually</option>
  </select>    
</div>
```

**Hint:** Make sure your CSS rules are included after the CSS files of Frameworks (like Bootstrap or Foundation). This way or using a selector with a higher specificity. These ways should be tried before using `!important` because using `!important` is not recommended.

Comment: brilliant - thanks LOADS. its works perfectly. i'll remember that one.

Comment: Please note that `!important` is ***not recommended***. It can be a valuable debugging tool to determine if specificity is the culprit, but if that turns out to be the case, the proper way to go about it is to find out what rule is overriding yours and to create a selector with a higher specificity. Leaving the `!important`s in will cause all kinds of frustration later, if someone wants to change one of those labels and finds out they can't.